# How to set next element values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a button, on click event on that I need to set value of next input hidden type element. I am trying below code  -

```
<span id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">

$(document).on('click','.myButtonClass',function(e){
  console.log($(this).closest(".search-id").length); // returning 0
  console.log($(this).next(".search-id").val()); // returning undefined
  if($(this).next(".search-id").length){
    var myval = $(this).next(".search-id").find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log('Val -'+myval);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `nextUntil` and `next` to get the desired input value as shown in below code

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.myButtonClass',function(e){
    var input = $(this).nextUntil(".search-id").next();
    console.log(input.length);
    console.log("value = " + $(input).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass">Button<i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg">Error</span>
<input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="Test Value" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">
```

OR you can use `nextAll` with `:first` selector

```js
 $(function(){
      $(document).on('click','.myButtonClass',function(e){
        var input = $(this).nextAll(".search-id:first");
        console.log(input.length);
        console.log("value = " + $(input).val());
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass">Button<i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    <span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg">Error</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="Test Value" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.next()` element is literally the next element in your HTML code, so in your case it's `<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg"></span>`

I adapted your code. `.find()` also excludes the current element. So if you run this on the element you want to find, it won't find it.

I updated your snippet a bit, just added a real button and some content. Other than that it's the same.

```js
$(document).on('click','.myButtonClass',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).next().next().length){
    var myval = $(this).next().next().val();
    console.log('Val -'+myval);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass">Click me!<i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="testvalue" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in place of `next()`.

Run below working code-

```js
$(document).on('click','.myButtonClass',function(e){
  console.log($(this).closest(".search-id").length); // returning 0
  console.log($(this).siblings("input:hidden.search-id").val()); // returning undefined
  if($(this).siblings("input:hidden.search-id").length){
    var myval = $(this).siblings("input:hidden.search-id").val();
    console.log('Val -'+myval);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass">Click Here<i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="Hidden Input Value" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $(this).next().next() function to find a input box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".myButtonClass").on('click',function(){
      $(this).next().next().val('Hello World')
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="clear_promotion_brand_search" class="myButtonClass"><i class="fa fa-times">click me</i></span>
<span id="error_brand" class="show-error-msg"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="promotion_brand_id" value="" data-id="brand" class="search-id is-validate form-fields-value">
```

[image]